# How to properly set Map as javaType in <arg> in MyBatis?

Tags: java, mybatis, lombok

### Problem description:

I have `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bar.Foo.<init>(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.util.Map)` when I try to get immutable Foo objects from DB with MyBatis and can't figure out what's wrong:(

I have an unsuccessful case by annotating result object with @Value and successful case annotating with @Data (they are below under corresponding headers). So, I'd like to use @Value but don't get what I'm doing wrong..

### Unsuccessful case:

So, I have the result class which is immutable:

```
@Value
public class Foo {
    long entryId;
    String description;
    Map<String, String> params;
}
```

It is stored in postgres in a table foos, `params` field value is stored in JSON format in a corresponding column of the same table (type is VARCHAR, entries are `"{key=value}"` in case of `params = Map.of("key", "value")`.
I'd like to instantiate my object of this class from DB and so I use the following MyBatis code:

```
<resultMap id="foo" type="bar.Foo">
     <constructor>
         <arg column="entry_id" javaType="java.lang.Long"/>
         <arg column="description" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
         <arg column="params" javaType="java.util.Map" jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="bar.MapToJsonStringHandler"/>
     </constructor>
</resultMap>
```

Here is my type handler (it's already been successfully used in another case with @Data object instead of @Value, so I guess it's correct by itself):

```
public class MapToJsonStringHandler implements TypeHandler<Map<String, String>> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @SneakyThrows(IOException.class)
    @Override
    public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, Map<String, String> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        if (parameter == null) {
        ps.setNull(i, Types.VARCHAR);
    } else {
        ps.setString(i, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(parameter));
    }
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    String result = rs.getString(columnName);
    return convertToMap(result);
}


@Override
public Map<String, String> getResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    String result = rs.getString(columnIndex);
    return convertToMap(result);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
    String result = cs.getString(columnIndex);
    return convertToMap(result);
}

@SneakyThrows(IOException.class)
private Map<String, String> convertToMap(String result) {
    return result == null ? Collections.emptyMap() : objectMapper.readValue(result, Map.class);
}
```

}

Here is SQL:

```
<select id="getFoos" resultMap="foo">
     SELECT *
     FROM foos
     <![CDATA[WHERE needed_tm < now()]]>
</select>
```

And when I get my Foos I have `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bar.Foo.<init>(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.util.Map)`.

Funny thing is that it works like a charm when I use @Data instead of @Value:

### Successful case:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
    long entryId;
    String description;
    Map<String, String> params;
}

<resultMap id="foo" type="bar.Foo">
     <result column="entry_id" property="entryId"/>
     <result column="description" property="description"/>
     <result column="params" property="params" typeHandler="bar.MapToJsonStringHandler"/>
</resultMap>
```

SQL and type handler are the same that in unsuccessful case.

May you be so kind to give me a hint what I am possibly missing? Thanks in advance!

### Update 1:

```
@Value
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
     long entryId;
     String description;
     Map<String, String> params;
}
```

gives the same exception. Anyway as I understand, @Value already has @AllArgsConstructor by design (https://projectlombok.org/features/Value)

Comment: I am going to be shooting in the dark here, since I think Java autoboxing should figure it out, but change your long to Long and use Value same as you have done

Comment: Hi Nick. Marking an answer will mark the question as "solved". No need to edit it in your title or question. I've rolled back to the previous version of your question to remove the mentions of "solved".

Comment: Hi TT, thanks, ok:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: bar.Foo.(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String, java.util.Map)  <--- Means there is no constructor defined.

When you use
@AllArgsConstructor, you are telling lombok to generate a constructor with all the arguments, (Long, String, Map), that is why that works for you.

According to documentation @Data:

@Data
All together now: A shortcut for @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode, @Getter on all fields, @Setter on all non-final fields, and @RequiredArgsConstructor

https://projectlombok.org/features/Data

That is why at that point it finds a constructor and does not give you an error (NoSuchMethod) when you use @Data.

---

```
<resultMap id="foo" type="bar.Foo">
     <constructor>
         <arg column="entry_id" javaType="java.lang.Long"/>
         <arg column="description" javaType="java.lang.String"/>
         <arg column="params" javaType="java.util.Map" jdbcType="VARCHAR" typeHandler="bar.MapToJsonStringHandler"/>
     </constructor>
</resultMap>
```

Since you are specifying the datatype to be java.lang.Long, it expects the constructor to be defined to have that parameter type.

I believe with @Data, it is not the constructor that helped you, it was the Setters (boxing) long To Long.

Try to use @Value, and change long to Long in your class.  See if that works.

Lombok will generate a constructor with (long, String, Map), not (Long, String, Map)

Curious to know what java version you are using.

Comment: Thank you! After I changed class fields to Long it works finally:)

Comment: Our of curiosity, what java version are you using :) @Nick

Comment: Java 11, jdk 11.0.9